# Wordpress CSS breaks after transfer to new domain with SSL

Tags: php, css, wordpress, ssl

I have transferred my website to a new domain with SSL and now CSS breaks. I tried installing WP Simple SSL plugin and it doesn't work. Also tried adding this line into my wp-confing.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

But that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Here is a website link: https://scilatech.com/

Here is error log:

```
[Wed Nov 08 23:48:34.749737 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 11008] [client 122.55.14.126:56780] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/scilatec/public_html/wp-content/themes/easyweb/css/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,Index.html,index.shtml,index.php,Index.php,index.phtml,Index.phtml,index.htm,Index.htm,default.htm,Default.htm,default.html,Default.html,home.htm,Home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Wed Nov 08 23:11:29.324765 2017] [:notice] [pid 47287] [client 178.220.189.14:39088] mod_hive matched URI http://scilatech.com/wp-login.php (/home/scilatec/public_html/wp-login.php) with match 2, referer: https://scilatech.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fscilatech.com%2Fwp-admin%2Foptions-general.php%3Fsettings-updated%3Dtrue&reauth=1
[Wed Nov 08 23:10:40.254933 2017] [:notice] [pid 36611] [client 178.220.189.14:34150] mod_hive matched URI http://scilatech.com/wp-login.php (/home/scilatec/public_html/wp-login.php) with match 2, referer: https://scilatech.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fscilatech.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

Comment: *https://scilatech.com/wp-content/themes/easyweb/css/master-min.php?ver=2.2.3* shows 502 bad gateway. Check your error logs

Comment: Check your console if there is some errors or check view source and then click on css links so you can find is it including  properly on new path or not

Comment: @rai How can I check error log? I added this to wp-config.php define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
but still no debug.log on my wp-content folder

Comment: Open your nginx config and find the **error_log** directive. That's where your error log points to.

Comment: @rai sorry I am not very skilled with that. I am using cPanel here, can you please help where can I open nginx config and do that?

Comment: this is what I find in cpanel error log:

Comment: [Wed Nov 08 23:48:34.749737 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 11008] [client 122.55.14.126:56780] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/scilatec/public_html/wp-content/themes/easyweb/css/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,Index.html,index.shtml,index.php,Index.php,index.phtml,Index.phtml,index.htm,Index.htm,default.htm,Default.htm,default.html,Default.html,home.htm,Home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: [Wed Nov 08 23:11:29.324765 2017] [:notice] [pid 47287] [client 178.220.189.14:39088] mod_hive matched URI http://scilatech.com/wp-login.php (/home/scilatec/public_html/wp-login.php) with match 2, referer: https://scilatech.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fscilatech.com%2Fwp-admin%2Foptions-general.php%3Fsettings-updated%3Dtrue&reauth=1

Comment: [Wed Nov 08 23:10:40.254933 2017] [:notice] [pid 36611] [client 178.220.189.14:34150] mod_hive matched URI http://scilatech.com/wp-login.php (/home/scilatec/public_html/wp-login.php) with match 2, referer: https://scilatech.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fscilatech.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: that was me accessing the directory instead of the file. re-visit https://scilatech.com/wp-content/themes/easyweb/css/master-min.php?ver=2.2.3 and check the logs again

Comment: its still showing the same error. But now I added all those css files from that folder manually in <head> section and it works now